# Edit Docker Container On AWS EC2

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a docker container running on AWS EC2. I am able to ssh into EC2 and edit the code running in the container, the problem is that those changes are not reflected on the respective website. It behaves like there is some kind of caching taking place with EC2 but can't find any caching going on. How do I get those changes to take effect? I am at a loss; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your browser caching the website? Have you tried emptying the cache and reloading?

Comment: How is the code loaded into the container? If the code gets copied when you build the image then you have to rebuild the image for each code change. If the code is mounted using the `-v` flag to the image then the changes should be immediate. Can you post your docker run command?

Comment: @quasar These are the commands that are being run:

`docker create --volume /var/www/html --name="code-data-volume-container" alpine:3.7 /bin/true`

`docker cp ./ code-data-volume-container:/var/www/html`

Then this is run:
`docker run --detach --name="php-fpm" --network="local-network" --volumes-from="code-data-volume-container" --workdir="/var/www/html" `